# PHP - Returning a variable from a function (return not working)

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, url-rewriting

For a specific scenario in WordPress, I'm trying to append '/blog' in between my domain and `wp-admin`, so it could look like `http://example.com/blog/wp-admin`

I already have a .htaccess file that rewrites the url for 99% of the site, but it doesn't rewrite the url generated by filtering by date/category.

Another solution that works would be editing the core file `edit.php` to include '/blog' but I rather not touch the core files

Here's what it looks like when I change `edit.php`, which works:

```
elseif ( ! empty($_REQUEST['_wp_http_referer']) ) {
   wp_redirect( '/blog' . remove_query_arg( array('_wp_http_referer', '_wpnonce'), wp_unslash($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ) );
   exit;
}
```

Here's my plugin that I'm trying to write to solve the issue without touching the core:

```
function change_filter_URL() {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin') === 0) {
    echo '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '<br>';
    $url = '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    return $url;
    echo $url;
  }
}
add_action('init', 'change_filter_URL');
```

if I comment out `return $url;` and leave `echo $url;`, it echoes to correct URL. but my current issue is that `return $url` doesn't return/output anything. the first `echo` works. I was wondering how could I correctly return `$url` ?

Comment: my assumption is that the `init` action is not expecting a returned value, it's just a trigger on initialization. see `wp-settings.php` for `do_action( 'init' );`

Comment: @Scuzzy I've tried other hooks that triggers earlier, such as `muplugins_loaded`, `plugins_loaded` and `after_setup_theme` in accordance to [this thread]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23631/what-is-the-very-earliest-action-hook-you-can-call) but they don't work either, but I'll continue to investigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect queries to the correct URL using `header()`:

```
function change_filter_URL() {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin') === 0 &&
      strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/blog/') === FALSE) {
    $url = '/blog' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header('Location: '.$url);  
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! your solution works for the most part -- there was this specific part of wp-admin that doesn't get rewritten with `/blog` that I'm trying to add `/blog` to. i think my line `if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/wp-admin') === 0) {` is incorrect because it's targeting everything that has /wp-admin

Comment: so the function that you've provided targets everything that has `/wp-admin` after I log into the dashboard.. is there a way to specific target the url that's missing `/blog` ?

`http://example.com/wp-admin` -> `http://example.com/blog/wp-admin`

Comment: I have updated the answer to check if the requested URI already contains `/blog/`. Does this work for you, or do you want to redirect all pages, not only `wp-admin` ones ?

Comment: Ah I've realized my mistake! It's because this function is executed before .htaccess rewrites the URL from `blog.example.com` to `example.com/blog` -- is it possible to load this function after .htaccess rewrites the URL?

Comment: but your function makes sense and it's perfect! thank you so much for your help